# What is the difference between binaries in ~/.rustup vs ~/.cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

I just installed Rust with rustup on MacOS and noticed that there are two `rustc` and two `cargo` binaries:

- `~/.cargo/bin/rustc (cargo)`
- `~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/rustc (cargo)`

Their versions are exactly the same, but `diff` shows there exists some difference. So why are there two different `rustc` (`cargo`) binaries and which one should I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason there are two files named `rustc` is because rustup is a toolchain multiplexer. It lets you install many versions of Rust and easily switch between them.

The binary installed at `~/.cargo/bin/rustc` proxies to the current toolchain that you have selected. Each installed compiler is kept under the `toolchains` directory.

Although the compiler in the `toolchains` directory appears to be a smaller file, that's only because it's dynamically linked instead of statically linked.

More information can be found on [rustup's README](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/tree/cef627130947d2e7a20f88030c357b11d1c1bb1f#how-rustup-works).

Comment: So the binaries in `.cargo` are basically proxies to the current toolchain, right?

Comment: @ZizhengTai Yes, exactly.

Comment: @squiguy: You might want to expand your answer to explain why the files are different.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Done. Feel free to edit my answer(s) in the future.

Comment: @ZizhengTai to clarify, the `cargo`, `rust-gdb`, `rust-lldb`, `rustc`, `rustdoc`, and `rustup` binaries in `.cargo/bin/` are all *the same* file. The first 5 all proxy to the relevant toolchain file.